# Unable to retrieve a single recordset using FirstOrDefault and pass it to the view

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I am currently not getting any value while trying to retrieve a single recordset for my detail view using `FirstOrDefault`. If I use `First` instead of `FirstOrDefault`, it fetches the record. Is it alright using the `First` keyword? Not sure what I am doing wrong.

**Controller**

```cs
public PartialViewResult LoadRequestHeaderTabView(int id) {
    if (id == 0 ) {
        return null;
    } else {
 request);
        var request = requestRepository.GetRequesById(id);
        return PartialView("~/Views/Request/_RequestHeader.cshtml", Mapper.Map<List<RequestViewModel>>(request));
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```cs
public Request GetRequesById(int id) {
    if (MCRHelper.UserValidate() == 1) {
        var requestById = db.spGetRequestByID("en", "GB", id).Select(t => new Request()).FirstOrDefault();
        return Mapper.Map<Request>(requestById);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**View**

```html
@model CC.GRP.MCRequest.ViewModels.RequestViewModel
<style>
.requestDetail {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif, sans-serif;
}
</style>
<div class="requestDetail">
    <div class="row">
        <div>@Html.Label("Country Number", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "editor-label col-sm-2" })</div><div class="col-sm-2 editor-field">@(Model.CountryCode)</div>
        <div>@Html.Label("Company Code", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "editor-label col-sm-2" })</div><div class="col-sm-2">@(Model.CompanyCode)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div>@Html.Label("Customer Number", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "editor-label col-sm-2" })</div><div class="col-sm-2 editor-field">@(Model.CustomerNumber)</div>
        <div>@Html.Label("Customer Shortname", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "editor-label col-sm-2" })</div><div class="col-sm-2 editor-field">@(Model.CustomerShortname)</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are ignoring whatever there is in your database and returning a new `Request` object instead. Not sure if that is what you meant.

Comment: No I dont want to ignore my database. When I use the First keyword it pulls the record. I thought the select just populates the model with the record from the database

Comment: The `Select` transforms the underlying element into something else and passes that on. `t => new Request()` transforms the underlying record `t` by ignoring it and returning a new blank `Request`.

Comment: Then how is my viewmodel getting populated with the recordset ?